# Attributed string not working on Label

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I am setting attribute on label my code is written below,
the only problem is my font and color is not getting rendered on label .

```
func setDataWithContent(content: EmbeddedContent) {

        if let htmlString = content.text {
            do {
                let encodedData = htmlString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                let attributedOptions : [String: AnyObject] = [
                    NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                    NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding,
                    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Regular", size:16)!,
                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()
                ]
                let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
                htmlTextLabel.attributedText = attributedString

            } catch {
                fatalError("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }

    }
```

can anyone help?

Comment: That's normal. Look at the doc of `NSAttributedString(data:options:documentsAttributes:)`. `NSFontAttributeName` and `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` will be ignored. At them afterward to the `attributedString` (may use then an `NSMutableAttributedString` to be able to modify its attributes.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NSAttributedString(data:options:documentsAttributes)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:) doesn't support `NSFontAttributeName` and `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` in its options.
They will be ignored.

So, you have to use a `NSMutableAttributedString`, and add your own effects afterwards:

```
let encodedData = htmlString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

let attributedOptions : [String: AnyObject] = [
    NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
    NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding
]
let attributedString = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
let addedEffects:[String:AnyObject] = [                                    
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Regular", size:16)!,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()
]
attributedString.addAttributes(addedEffects, range:NSRange(location:0,length:attributedString.length)
htmlTextLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Note: I don't know if it compiles, but you should get the idea.

*I posted the answer to have a "Swift way" of understanding the issue, but it's clearly a duplicate and will happily delete the answer if the question if flagged as such.*

Comment: You can't delete this answer after it has been accepted.

Comment: Oops, didn't expected that. Thought also that the OP would mark its question as a duplicate.